# ETL using AWS Lambda and Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Background: I'd like to collect data from an existing system to perform Analytics processing.

The existing system exposes REST endpoint.

Hard Requirement: MVP (minimum viable product) => preferred AWS Lambda or something light and should end in Redshift, no extra storage/archival is required (no need to store in S3).

My plan is to use AWS Lambda to perform interval collection and do transformation and store the data to AWS Redshift.

What are the suggested approach:

Soln #1: AWS Lambda for transformation + use PostgreSQL driver to insert?

Soln #2: AWS Lambda for transformation + push to AWS Kinesis => copy to AWS Redshift?

Any other solutions?

Comment: what is the event/trigger to kick off the processing? how much data is this and how often will it run?  how long will it run?

Comment: Yes, there will be trigger to kick off AWS Lambda.

Data won't be big, a few thousands records. We're still working on the frequency (some Lambdas will run once a month, some will run once every hour). Some lambdas might take less than 5 mins to run => I have not tested the writing-to-Redshift part as that is still under investigation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data volume that you need to ingest into Redshift? Let say you schedule Lambda to run every 30 min, get a batch of data & insert into Redshift, make sure it can complete within 15min execution time.

I prefer Lambda --> Kinesis Firehose --> Redshift as it can scale better.
But if the volume is small or cost is a factor then you #1 is also a good choice.

Comment: I read somewhere that transferring data from Kinesis (wasn't mentioned whether through Firehose or not) to Redshift is preferred over sending prepared-statement one by one.

Volume is definitely small, probably a few thousands records. 

Concern is more on the reliability: cost of writing extra code in Lambda to ensure all insert operations are successful.

Comment: By the way, is it slightly easier to choose S3 instead?

AWS Lambda => S3 => COPY => Redshift?

Comment: "I read somewhere that transferring data from Kinesis (wasn't mentioned whether through Firehose or not) to Redshift is preferred ...."
For sure this one is Kinesis Firehose, still behind the scene it produce data into S3 before issue a COPY command to Redshift.
This is one of the example
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-redshift-firehose-stream.html

Comment: The nice thing about Firehose is you don't have to write any code/Lambda to insert data. Firehose also natively handle back pressure, undelivered data will be sent to another S3 bucket, where you can use it to issue another COPY command to Redshift. --> reduce your effort & cost of writing Lambda with error/exception handling.

Comment: "By the way, is it slightly easier to choose S3 instead? AWS Lambda => S3 => COPY => Redshift? "

This will save some cost by not using Firehose, but your Lambda have to handle object creation in S3 & handle error/exception as well. Remember that writing too frequently to S3 might incur extra cost  (S3 charge by number of read/write requests), while with Firehose you can set a S3 buffer (by size or by fixed interval) & only write to S3 when necessary